# Fast way to check for the existence of images on a remote server

Tags: asp.net, cdn

I have a website which loads images from a CDN. I have a requirement to check for the existence of 100s of images on the CDN.

I am using this code to achieve  this:

```
Protected Function RemoteImageExists(ByVal Path As String) As Boolean

    Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(Path), HttpWebRequest)

    httpRequest.Method = "HEAD"

    Try

        Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(httpRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False 'Undesirable flow, but seems unavoidable :(
    End Try

    Return True

End Function
```

This is still very slow, and many requests timeout. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: I have a stupid question: does the CDN you use allows to serve dynamic content? (If yes, the faster way would be to host a service on the CDN, returning the list of available images).

Comment: How frequently do you need to run this check?  And when/where is it called?  You could check for 300/400 level responses, etc. to make it more intelligent.

Comment: I've just realized that something's wrong - setting a breakpoint shows that each request is taking minutes! Something's seriously screwed!

I am doing this via admin, so speed isn't a huge factor - but the current rate of the page is ridiculously low, and now appears to be for some other reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several suggestions:

1. If the CDN can serve dynamic content, hosting a service on the CDN which will deliver the list of images would be the best approach in terms of performances.
2. Are the images in the same directory? If yes, configure CDN to show the list of files available, and query this list. Parsing HTML is an ugly thing, but since the format of those HTML files will not change unexpectedly one day, it can be an acceptable.
3. If the first two are impossible, use `Parallel` extensions depending on circumstances (it may make things faster or slower).
4. Exceptions are slow. Get rid of them. Using sockets directly may help (even if it's ugly).

By the way, finding the bottleneck may help finding a better solution. For example, if the bottleneck is the processor power, Parallel extensions may help, but if is the bandwidth or CDNs performances, it will just slow everything down. Note that the bottleneck may be either the local machine, the local connection, the overall connection or the CDN.

Comment: Found a solution - the CDN (Rackspace) has an API I can use to get the file list. Thanks for your suggestions!